# Re-arrange data so a single cell is header

Tags: r

I am looking to re-arrange my data. Currently it looks like data 1 and I would like for it to look like data2. Essentially, I would like to move 'total' so that it is its own column, and I'd like to move its n along with it. I am using R. Thank you.

```
data1 <- data.frame (
  question = c("recommend", "recommend", "overall", "overall"),
  response = c("top box score", "total", "top box score", "total"),
  n = c(673, 784, 654, 784))


data2 <- data.frame (
  question = c("recommend", "overall"),
  response = c("top box score", "top box score"),
  n = c(673, 654),
  total = c(784, 784))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table` as follows:

```
library(data.table)
data2 <- setDT(data1)[response != "total"][data1, total := i.n, on = "question"]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to filter data for `"total"` rows, get them in wide format and join to the original data without `"total"` rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data1 %>% 
  filter(response != 'total') %>%
  left_join(data1 %>%
          filter(response == 'total') %>%
          pivot_wider(names_from = response, values_from = n), by = 'question')

#   question      response   n total
#1 recommend top box score 673   784
#2   overall top box score 654   784
```